# Magento 2 - Why is less file loading first?

Tags: xml, magento, magento2

I am using grunt/M2 & I noticed my less files are loading before my css files in my Magento 2 website. Any ideas? I need the less file to load last so it overwrites classes...

-Thanks so much!

Here is whats in my theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
    <css src="css/local-m.css" />
    <css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/source/_custom.css" /> <!-- This is the less file -->
   </head>
   </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1821 you can see that they recommend adding `load_last="true"`. I've used it and it works as expected.

Here's the full line:

```
<css src="css/custom.css" load_last="true" />
```

I will add an additional note and let you know that I started down this route until I learned how to override/extend specific module LESS. Here's a Magento document providing an example scenario: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_practice.html

Answer (score 0):

There was one attribute with import CSS with XML. Please check below default_headd_blocks.xml file.

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

You can try to two way

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_Module::css/custom.css" order="100"/>
</head>
```

OR

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_Module::css/custom.css" media="all"/>
</head>
```

Please let me know if you have any issues.